# Ubuntu Budgie 17.10 Greeter Wallpaper black

Tags: login, 17.10, lightdm, desktop-background, ubuntu-budgie

on my freshly installed Ubuntu Budgie 17.10 the greeter shows a black wallpaper instead of the out-of-the-box wallpaper.

How can I set the greeter-wallpaper?
I created a file /etc/lightdm/slick-greeter.conf with the following content:

```
[Greeter]
background=/usr/share/backgrounds/Xplo_by_Hugo_Cliff.png
theme-name=Abiant-MATE-Dark
icon-theme-name=Ambiant-Mate
draw-grid=false
```

But it doesn't change anything.
Has this something to do with my fully encrypted installation?
Cheers
Johkra

Answer (score 0):

Actually I found out what the issue was.

Apparently I am the only one having a simple color as a wallpaper.
In that case the login-wallpaper is broken and only shows a black wallpaper even a different color is selected.

Cheers